# How to define a SERVER_API_URL to a jhipster gateway application?

Tags: javascript, java, gulp, jhipster, gateway

I have a jhipster gateway application that has no back-end structure. **It was created with --skip-server** option.
When I run the gateway application with the commando **GULP** the port defined is 8080 but The jhipster API application is on 8081 . How to define this default url?

I changed in the file:

> gulp/config.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    app: 'src/main/webapp/',
    dist: 'build/www/',
    swaggerDist: 'build/www/swagger-ui/',
    test: 'src/test/javascript/',
    bower: 'src/main/webapp/bower_components/',
    tmp: 'build/tmp',
    revManifest: 'build/tmp/rev-manifest.json',
    port: 8080,
    apiPort: 8081,
    liveReloadPort: 35729,
    uri: 'http://localhost:',
    constantTemplate:
        '(function () {\n' +
        '    \'use strict\';\n' +
        '    // DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n' +
        '    angular\n' +
        '        .module(\'<%- moduleName %>\')\n' +
        '<% constants.forEach(function(constant) { %>        .constant(\'<%- constant.name %>\', <%= constant.value %>)\n<% }) %>;\n' +
        '})();\n' };
```

But it did not work. What can I do?

Comment: Is there a `serverPort` property in `.yo-rc.json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `SERVER_API_URL` variable pre-configured for AngularJS projects.  It is only present in Angular (v4+) JHipster projects by default.  Because of this, all AngularJS services send requests to the API based on a relative path to where they are hosted (usually port 8080 or 9000). `gulp` then proxies any requests from port 9000 to the API port defined in `gulp/config.js`.

To customize the `SERVER_API_URL` throughout the project, you can add a config variable to `app.constants.js`. To do this, add a `SERVER_API_URL` to the `ngconstant:dev` and `ngconstant:prod` sections in your [`gulpfile.js`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/v3.12.2/gulpfile.js#L98-L124). Running `gulp` will inject the variable into `app.constants.js`.

Once the variable is present in `app.constants.js`, you can inject it into your service JS files that use AngularJS's `$resource` or `$http`.    For example in [`account.service.js`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/v3.12.2/src/main/webapp/app/services/auth/account.service.js#L11), you should inject `SERVER_API_URL` and change the URL from just `'api/account'` to `SERVER_API_URL + 'api/account'`.

You can see a full list of files that use AngularJS's `$resource` and `$http` by searching with your IDE or using a tool like grep: `grep -R '$resource\|$http' ./src/main/webapp/app`